# Custom taxonomy sort by term meta in admin columns

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

I want sorting custom taxonomy admin table with terms by terms meta. This meta is sort index of terms.

But I dont know how can do it. I use `add_filter('manage_edit-{}_sortable_columns')`
but sorting does work.

I use `add_filter( 'get_terms_args')`   but

```
$args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
$args['meta_key']   = 'tax_date';
```

without result. 
Are there some hook or filter?